# Proof that $3^n | 2^{3^n} + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

**Question:**

> Proof by induction that $3^n | 2^{3^n} + 1$.

**Attempt:** $$ 2^{3^{n+1}} + 1 = 2^{3^n}  2^3 + 1 = 2^{3^n}  2^3 + 1 + 2^3 - 2^3 = 
 2^3( 2^{3^n} + 1 ) + 1 -2^3$$

And the first is $3^n |$ but second I don't know how to proof that.

Comment: @jennifer I think your edit masks a substantial mistake made by the poster.

Comment: In the inductive step you must evaluate $$2^{3^{n+1}}+1=\left(2^{3^n}\right)^3+1$$ **not** $2^{3^n+1}+1=2^{3^n}\cdot 2+1$ which is again different from $2^{3^n}\cdot 2^3+1=2^{3^n+3}+1\neq 2^{3^{n+1}}+1$.

Comment: But 2^3^n * 2^3 is 2^3^{n+1}  ( 3^n * 3 is 3^{n+1} )

Comment: @zxc No, $2^{3^n}\cdot 2^3 = 2^{3^n+3}$, not $2^{3^n\cdot 3}$.

Comment: @zxc No. $x^a\cdot x^b=x^{a+b}\neq x^{ab}$

Comment: Yes I see it now, You're right now I can proof it

Comment: You can also show by induction on $n$ that $\nu_{3}\left(2^{3^n}+1\right)=n+1$ for all $n=0,1,2,\ldots$.  Here, $\nu_3$ is the $3$-adic valuation.

Comment: In fact, we have a stronger statement: $3^{n+1}\mid 2^{3^n}+1$ and $3^{n+2}\nmid 2^{3^n}+1$. This follows from Lifting The Exponent Lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2^{3^m}+1=h\cdot 3^{m}\implies 2^{3^{m+1}}+1=(h\cdot 3^m-1)^3+1=\\=(h\cdot 3^m)((h\cdot 3^{m}-1)^2-(h\cdot 3^m-1)+1)=\\=(h\cdot 3^m)(h^2\cdot 3^{2m}-3h\cdot 3^m+3)$$ if  $m\ge 1$, then $3$ divides $h^2\cdot3^{2m}-3h\cdot 3^m+3$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $$(2^{3^n})^3 + 1 = \left(2^{3^n} +1\right) \left((2^{3^n})^2- 2^{3^n} +  1\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you should be looking at $2^{3^{n+1}}$, not $2^{3^n+1}$. Assume, by induction that $2^{3^n} + 1 = 3^nd$, i.e., $2^{3^n} = 3^nd - 1$, and see what you can get from $2^{3^{n+1}} + 1 = 2^{3^n\cdot 3} + 1 = (2^{3^n})^3 + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$2^{3^{n+1}}+1 = (2^{3^n})^3 + 1 = (2^{3^n}+1)((2^{3^n})^2 - 2^{3^n} + 1).$$ Can you take it from there?